# Why doesn't my HTML and JavaScript work on my iPad, but works on my PC?

Tags: javascript, html

I have made code about getting roots of quadratic formula. The code seems to work well on pc, but it doesn't work on my ipad1. I've searched a lot to solve this problem but I couldn't get answer. I think I cannot solve this problem on my own.

I used safari on ipad. I checked the update for ios and it was the latest.
Code below are both in body tag.

In my Ipad the result doesn't appear. I omitted some end tags at code but there are all end tags in my original file.

```js
function solve_qua() {
  var a = Number(document.getElementById("qua_a").value);
  var b = Number(document.getElementById("qua_b").value);
  var c = Number(document.getElementById("qua_c").value);

  var D = b * b - 4 * a * c;
  var root;

  if (D == 0) {
    root = (-1) * b / (2 * a);
    var sroot;
    var sroot = "x = " + root;
    document.getElementById("qua_answer").innerHTML = sroot;
  } else if (D < 0) {
    var s = -D;
    var coe1 = (-b) / (2 * a);
    var coe2 = (s ** 0.5) / (2 * a);
    var sroot1 = coe1 + " - " + coe2 + "i";
    var sroot2 = coe1 + " + " + coe2 + "i";
    var sroot = "x = " + sroot1 + "\n" + "or" + "\n" + "x = " + sroot2;
    document.getElementById("qua_answer").innerHTML = sroot;

  } else {
    var root1 = ((-b) - D ** 0.5) / (2 * a);
    var root2 = (-b + D ** 0.5) / (2 * a);
    var sroot = "x = " + root1 + "\n" + "or" + "\n" + "x = " + root2;
    document.getElementById("qua_answer").innerHTML = sroot;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="w3-row">
  <div class="w3-twothird w3-container">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <label for="qua_a">a =</label>
        <input type="text" id="qua_a">
      </li>
      <br>
      <li>
        <label for "qua_b">b =</label>
        <input type="text" id="qua_b">
      </li>
      <br>
      <li>
        <label for "qua_c">c =</label>
        <input type="text" id="qua_c">
      </li>
      <p><button onclick="solve_qua()">calculate</button></p>
      <p id="qua_answer"></p>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. The only allowed direct children of `ul` are `li`. Also stop redeclaring variables already declared with `var`.

Comment: How to debug: 1: Print the result without html tag. If it works, then the problem is in your html. 2: Use a remote debugger to debug your application. If your application breaks during execution, you will notice it. 3: Split your code in smaller functions and remove the pieces one by one. At some point, you should get some result

Comment: You can debug you code on an iPad, here's a tutorial of how to do it: https://support.brightcove.com/debugging-mobile-devices

Comment: This was my first question on stack overflow. Thanks for giving such a detailed answer. By doing a lot of inserting and deleting codes, I found out I cannot use ** operator on my ipad. Although it worked well on pc and other android devices it didn't worked well on my ipad. I am just a beginner on HTML so I don't know the reason why.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the characters are not supported on Apple devices. That's all I can suggest.